# How to shorten this sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem with shorting this sql code:

```
SELECT
(SELECT name FROM content_categories ccb WHERE ccb.id = (SELECT parent FROM content_categories cc WHERE cc.id = 57)) AS parent,
(SELECT id FROM content_categories ccb WHERE ccb.id = (SELECT parent FROM content_categories cc WHERE cc.id = 57)) AS parent_id,
(SELECT alias FROM content_categories ccb WHERE ccb.id = (SELECT parent FROM content_categories cc WHERE cc.id = 57)) AS parent_alias,
(SELECT name as subcategory FROM content_categories ccb WHERE ccb.id = 57) as sub,
(SELECT id as subcategory FROM content_categories ccb WHERE ccb.id = 57) as sub_id,
(SELECT alias as subcategory FROM content_categories ccb WHERE ccb.id = 57) as sub_alias
```

Can you please help me with ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT cp.name as parent, cp.id as parent_id, cp.alias as parent_alias,
       cc.name as sub, cc.id as sub_id, cc.alias as sub_alias
FROM content_categories cc left join
     content_categories cp
     on ccp.id = cc.parent
WHERE cc.id = 57;
```

The only difference is that this will return no rows if `cc.id = 57` does not exist.  Your version will return one row where all the columns are `NULL`.